# Mysql build row combinations

Tags: mysql

I have to generate 2 columns with the combinations of others 2. I have a column with product attributes and another column with attribute values, I need to achive this:

```
Attributes  Values
Color, Size Blue, L
Color, Size Blue, XL
Color, Size Red, L
Color, Size Red, XL
```

But I have this:

```
Attribute   Value
Color           Blue
Color           Red
Size            L
Size            XL
```

I don't see tha way to achieve this also I can have color,sizes,materials and other type of attributes

I tried with group_concat but didn't work for this example

````
SELECT 
p.products_id as 'product_id',
pd.products_name as 'name',
po.products_options_name as 'attributes',
trim(pov.products_options_values_name) as 'attribute_values'
-- GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(po.products_options_name)) as 'attributes',
-- GROUP_CONCAT(distinct(trim(pov.products_options_values_name))) as 'attribute_values'
FROM `products` AS p
INNER JOIN `products_description` AS pd ON p.`products_id` = pd.`products_id` 
INNER JOIN `products_attributes` AS pa ON p.`products_id` = pa.`products_id` 
INNER JOIN `products_options` AS po ON pa.`options_id` = po.`products_options_id` 
INNER JOIN `products_options_values` AS pov ON pa.`options_values_id` = pov.`products_options_values_id` 
WHERE p.products_id = '1476'
AND pd.language_id =3
group by trim(pov.products_options_values_name)
LIMIT 0 , 30```
````

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: This isn't "build row combinations" . This is using SQL to unwind data stored in an EAV model, and then using SQL to re-twist it back into a comma separated list (an anti-pattern).  But cool story bro. Thanks for the status report. Was there a question?

Comment: Also because SQL is defined to be orderless without ORDER BY, meaning using LiMIT without ORDER BY is pretty much meaningless

Comment: Also the GROUP BY isnt valid SQL

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks you for the information you are right 'bro', the question is very simple to understand though

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table is formatted as two columns with the names 'Attributes' and 'Values', this may work. It will return a single column with the concatenated values.

```
SELECT CONCAT(ca.Value,', ', cb.Value) AS 'Values' 
FROM (SELECT Value FROM table_name WHERE Attributes = 'Color') ca
CROSS JOIN (SELECT Value FROM table_name WHERE Attributes = 'Size') cb;
```

Just replace table_name with the name of your table.

Comment: The cross join will produce the Cartesian (or semi-Cartesian product), but we may also want to consider what should be returned when one of the inline views doesn't return any rows. We might want to have an inline view guaranteed to return a single row and do outer joins `FROM (SELECT 1 AS i) a LEFT JOIN (...) ca LEFT JOIN (...) cb LEFT JOIN (...) cc`  and then appropriately handle NULL values in the expression in the SELECT list  `CONCAT(IFNULL(ca.value,''),...`

Answer (score -3):

Please try the following

```
SELECT p.product_id || ',' || pd.products_name || ',' || po.products_options_name
FROM...
```

this will produce the results you need however you splitting them into two columns
concat and group_concat do work however you cannot use alias here for seperate selection nor in the previous method

Comment: check out the syntax for group_concat what you have commented out there if that was your attempt at concat then its wrong